# Keras {ValueError}: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_2

Tags: python, keras

I am new to keras, and I am trying to do a convolution over a document. Each document is represented by a matrix whose shape is [40 * 4000](every doc has 40 sentences and each sentences has 20 words, so word embedding dimension is 200).

I wanna do convolution over 3 words, this is my code(not exactly the same, but you can run this code on your machine):

```py
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dense, merge, Conv2D
from keras.layers.core import Reshape

tokens_input = Input(name='input', shape=(40, 20), dtype='int32')

x = Embedding(25000 + 1, 200, name="embedding")(tokens_input)
x = Reshape((40, -1), 
             name="reshape")(x)


cur_conv = Conv2D(20, kernel_size=(3*200, 1),
                 strides=(200, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
```

But I get this error message: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to a Conv2D layer should have shape (samples, channels, width, height), and the output from your Embedding is 3D, not 4D as it should be. You should define how to interpret the Embedding output as an image, maybe you should add a channels dimension and set it to 1.

Comment: Thanks,I solved the problem, But I read the keras doc of Conv2D and it says parameter kernel_size specifying the **width and height** of the 2D convolution window (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), in practice, I think kernel_size specifying **height and width**, in other words, rows and cols, am I right?

Comment: @Joey The width and height specified in the input shape corresponds to the input data, not to the convolutional filters. You can have an image that is much bigger than the convolutional filter.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it clearly. I mean the paramenter of Conv2D **kernel_size**,  the doc says it specifying the filters' **width and height**, but I found that it specifying filters' **height and width**, in other words, the rows and cols of filters.